How to get total time duration just after recorded video?
I am facing issue where: after successfully recording a video, I am not able to get video total time duration.
First the user starts a recording, then later the user needs to stop video recording. 
After stopping, how can I get the total video duration (video time length: i.e. 10m:20s) without reloading the video as a new file?
HTML part:
<video id="videoRecorded" controls></video>
 <button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>

JS part: Used MediaRecorder for creating webm video file recording.
async function main() {
            const videoRecorded= document.getElementById('videoRecorded');
            const buttonStart = document.querySelector('#start')
            const buttonStop = document.querySelector('#stop')
            const buttonsubmit = document.querySelector('#submit')

            let blob = null
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                video: true,
                audio: true,
            })
            videoRecorded.srcObject = stream;
            if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm')) {
                console.warn('video/webm is not supported')
            }

            const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
                mimeType: 'video/webm',
            })

            buttonStart.addEventListener('click', () => {
                mediaRecorder.start() //
                buttonStart.classList.add('hidden')
                buttonStop.classList.remove('hidden')
            })

            buttonStop.addEventListener('click', () => {
                mediaRecorder.stop()
            })

            mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {
                blob = new Blob([event.data], {type: 'video/mp4'});
                videoRecorded.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.data)
                videoRecorded.addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {
                    console.log(videoRecorded.duration)
                })
            })
        }

        main()

Note : Server side processing also good for this task

(1) PS:  If your recording mimeType == video/webm then you should later use Blob type: 'video/webm because your bytes are not MP4 data. Do not save such file as .mp4, use instead .webm as file type. (2) To get duration without re-loading the Blob as a Video .src then you must instead check the file bytes. This means searching the array and reading an integer from it. Can you work with arrays? I can help you check the duration in the bytes if you provide a link to a short test file that your code produces. PPS: Loading the video is easiest way...

Yes  we are ok with array.... can you provide code block related to bytes? so we can integrate...

No worries if you can't provide a 10 second test file. I found this example webm from https://darkcoding.net/software/reading-mediarecorders-webm-opus-output/ ... Anyways it seems the two bytes for duration entry (is 44 89) do not exist. File is from 2018, so I don't know if Chrome has changed anything since... Anyways you cannot "get total time duration just after recording" because the number does not exist in the recording. The solution would be to keep track of time during recording and manually add it into the file after recording..

PS: You want how to get but I can only show you to how to add duration (or extract an existing one), but if you don't have a known actual duration number to write in there then we can stop now and call it unsolvable... PS: If duration existed, then you'd put your recording into an array and look for any if( myChunk[ i ] == 0x44 ) and then confirm if [ i + 1] == 0x89 for the next byte value. If both are found, then the next 8 bytes represent the duration. You can now read it or change it etc.

If you use Node.js for server side then try:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-video-duration
Usage example (from documentation):
const { getVideoDurationInSeconds } = require('get-video-duration')

//# From a local path...
getVideoDurationInSeconds('video.mov').then((duration) => { console.log(duration) })

//# From a URL...
getVideoDurationInSeconds(
  'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4'
).then((duration) => { console.log(duration) })

//# From a readable stream...

const fs = require('fs')
const stream = fs.createReadStream('video.mov')

getVideoDurationInSeconds(stream).then((duration) => { console.log(duration) })

//# If you need to customize the path to ffprobe...
getVideoDurationInSeconds('video.mov', '/path/to/ffprobe').then((duration) => { console.log(duration) })


I assume you don't want to calculate the duration using time interval. If you want to get the "official" duration you can utilize timer to wait for the value, because it is Infinty until after the stream has been fully loaded which in turn only happens a few moments after play().
So that's it. A little weak especially if the video is long.
mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {

  blob = new Blob([event.data], {
    type: 'video/webm'
  });
  videoRecorded.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.data)

  videoRecorded.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', (event) => {
    videoRecorded.currentTime = 0
    videoRecorded.play()
    checkDuration()
  })
})

function checkDuration() {
  if (videoRecorded.duration === Infinity) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      checkDuration();
    }, 50);
  } else {
    console.log(videoRecorded.duration)
    URL.revokeObjectURL(videoRecorded.src)
  }
}


It seems the OP was recording with mimeType: 'video/webm' but somehow then loading the output Blob as video/mp4.

If video length is more than 2 hour then user need to wait till video play completely.

well, it might buffer a little before then. also, i guess it would take the same time to upload to server.
